# if statement doesnt work in C despite meeting condition

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while(true)
    {
        c = scanf("%d", &c);
        if(c==12)
        {
            printf("goes in");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am still learning C and I got stuck here. My code is pretty simple but I have no idea why it's not working.
The while loop functions normally however I cannot access the if statement despite meeting the condition.

Thank you!

Comment: The format string has only one conversion specifier, so `scanf` can only return 0, 1, or EOF.  It is not possible for `c` to equal 12 after the `scanf` call.  You probably meant to do `int c, d; ... d = scanf("%d", c); ...`. But notice that even with this extremely simple usage of `scanf`, your program will have undefined behavior on certain inputs.  As a beginner to C, you should *stop* *using* *scanf*.  Just forget the function even exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scanf` function returns the number of patterns matched.  So if you type a number and press ENTER, that number will first be stored in `c` by the function, then it will return the value 1 to indicate that 1 value was read.  That return value of 1 is then assigned to `c`, overwriting whatever number you entered.

Skip the assignment, and `c` will have the value you entered.

```
scanf("%d", &c);
if(c==12)
{
    printf("goes in");
    break;
}
```

Or better yet, assign the return value to a different variable to see if a number was in fact entered.

```
int rval = scanf("%d", &c);
if(rval == 1 && c==12)
{
    printf("goes in");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, since `c` was not initialized, it is essential to check that `scanf` returned 1.  Otherwise, attempting to read the value of `c` is undefined behavior.  Of course, on certain inputs (namely, if the string represents an integer that cannot be stored in an int), the `scanf` call itself is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is full of pitfalls.  (http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). As a beginner, you would do well to avoid it completely.  (As a programmer of any level, it is wise to avoid it!). To do even this simple program robustly, you must do a few things.  Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int
main(void)
{
    int c, rv;
    while( (rv = scanf("%3d", &c)) != EOF ){
        if( rv == 0 ){
            int k;
            /* Consume a line of input */
            while( (k = getchar()) != EOF && k != '\n' ){
                ;
            }
        } else if( c == 12 ){
            printf("goes in\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since `c` was not initialized, the program's behavior is undefined if you attempt to read its value without first assigning it.  `scanf` may return without assigning a value, and if you do not check the value returned by `scanf` to ensure that it is 1, you cannot read the value of `c`.  Also, using `%d` is always subject to undefined behavior, since it is possible to read a string that represents a value that cannot fit in an integer.  By using `%3d`, we avoid that possibility (the language standard specifies that an integer can hold all integer values between -99 and 999).  Finally, you need to consume data if `scanf` returns 0, since a return of 0 indicates that `scanf` did not consume any data.  (That's not quite what a zero return means, but it is in this case.) If you attempt to call `scanf` again without consuming data, the program will sit in a spin loop.

Your best bet as a beginner is to simply stop using `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

As already was pointed to you are reassigning the variable `c` that gets its value in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &c);
           ^^^^
```

with the return value of the function `scanf`

```
c = scanf("%d", &c);
```

According to the C Standard (7.21.6.4 The scanf function)

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
> Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
> assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
> event of an early matching failure.

I have written my answer because I'd like to suggest to rewrite the while loop the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int c;
    while ( scanf("%d", &c) == 1 )
    {
        if ( c == 12 )
        {
            printf( "goes in\n" );
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or as the variable `c` is used only within the body of the while loop then it is better to use for loop in the scope of which the variable `c` will be declared. You should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for ( int c; scanf("%d", &c) == 1; )
    {
        if ( c == 12 )
        {
            printf( "goes in\n" );
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```